# Java - JDK Update information

Tags: java

I need to update Java version

```
java version "1.4.2"
```

I don't want change version of my jdk, so if I update java, will JDK update too?

EDIT

@UnholySheep

> You mean you want to update the JRE (runtime environment)? That is
>   indeed separate from the JDK

Comment: You mean you want to update the JRE (runtime environment)? That is indeed separate from the JDK (though 1.4.2 is absolutely ancient, why are you still developing with that?)

Comment: yes JRE
I'm still using 1.4.2 cause my client use that version, but we need do update JRE for some programs but in the same time we need to use JDK 1.5

Comment: 15+ year old java version, ouch.

Comment: 15+ years old really?
i'm newbie about JRE, usually i work with Oracle DB

Comment: If it's not absolutely necessity for you to use JDK /JRE 1.4, I would suggest that you download the latest version of Java.That said, you can have different JDK and JRE versions on the same machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`java -version` will update only if you point the java environment variable to the new JDK/JRE installation.

You can have multiple JDK installations and switch between them whenever you like. For the current JDK in use you just have to set (On Windows) the  JAVA_HOME environment variable to point to the correct JDK folder you intend to use at the moment.

Of course, this is only helpful for use in the command line. If you are using an IDE it's even simpler, you can choose/switch the JDK you want to use on every Java Project from the Project Settings.

For Linux, you can change the current JDK in use like this:

```
export $JAVA_HOME=/urs/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_144/jre

export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to upgrade your Java version in your Linux system
then you can go with

```
sudo upgrade java
```